# cannot get right result from getdefaultsharedpreferences

Tags: java, android

When I use defaultsharedpreferences to save multiple data, I found data is covered. I feel confused about what happened. The expected values from preferences

```
userId is 2 
authorizedHeader is bhlrYXZpbjpseWthdmlu
```

and retrieved values

```
userId is 2 
authorizedHeader is 2
```

[image: image show the result]

```
private static final String PREF_AUTHORIZED_QUERY = null;

private static final String PREF_USERID_QUERY = null;

public static String getStoredUserIdQuery(Context context){
    return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
            .getString(PREF_USERID_QUERY, null);
}

public static String getStoredAuthorizedQuery(Context context){
    return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
            .getString(PREF_AUTHORIZED_QUERY, null);
}

public static void setStoredQuery(Context context, String userId, String authorizedHeader){
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
            .edit()
            .putString(PREF_AUTHORIZED_QUERY, authorizedHeader)
            .putString(PREF_USERID_QUERY, userId)
            .apply();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using values as `null` for both keys mean there is only one key i.e. `null` which will override the each other (`PREF_USERID_QUERY` will over write previous values which were saved with `null` as key)

so give them values

```
private static final String PREF_AUTHORIZED_QUERY = "authorized";

private static final String PREF_USERID_QUERY = "userid";
```

You can imagine it like

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
            .edit()
            .putString("null", authorizedHeader)
            .putString("null", userId) // so there is actually only one key 
            .apply();
```